# orderBy on hasMany Relationship with pagination in laravel

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent, sql-order-by, laravel-pagination

Act Review is connected to "Act_master" with this relationship.
One-Act can have many reviews on it.

```
public function reviews() {
    return $this->hasMany('ActReview', 'act_id', 'id');
}
```

**Question**: **How should I get act list order by max review count to lowest review count.**

**What I have tried so far?**

I have added the query with "whereHas" but the result list is not get the desired result as act list with highest to lowest review.

I have also tried "WITH" but that also not working.

Please guide me if possible to get the act list as per max review count to the lowest reviewer count.

```
   $list   = ActMaster::where('status', '=', '1');

    $list = $list->whereHas('reviews',function ($query) {
        $query->select(\DB::raw('count(*) as row_count'));
        $query->where('published', '=', '1');
        $query->orderBy('row_count','desc');
        $query->groupBy('act_id');                
    });

    $list = $list->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$list = ActMaster::where('status', 1)->whereHas('reviews', function($query){
    $query->select(\DB::raw('count(*) as row_count'))
          ->where('published', '1')
          ->groupBy('act_id')
          ->orderBy('row_count','desc');
})->paginate(10);
```

Comment: thanks but still the same result the Act list is not getting sort (order by) row count

Comment: $lists = ActMaster::where('status', 1)->withCount(['reviews as reviews_count' => function($query){
$query->where('published', 1);
}])->orderBy('reviews_count', 'desc')->paginate(10);

Comment: in blade using {{ $list->reviews_count }}

Comment: this sorts within relationship not complete object